# How to populate a database in sqlite3 using shell script while extracting data from files

Tags: shell, sql, sqlite

I have many .dat files containing specific fields such as `<Overall>, <Content>, <Cleanliness>` all with a number next to them.

I have the code to be able to extract the data from these fields using awk and sed commands, however how would I go about adding this data into a table in sqlite3?

Is there a way I can add all the values from a temporary file into a column?

Answer (score 1):

what about ..

```
... | awk '{print "insert into T1 value(\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")\n",$1,$2,$3}' > tmp.sql
```

then insert tmp.sql ?

using mysql I usualy do

```
 ... | awk '{print "insert into T1 value(\"%s\",\"%s\",\"%s\")\n",$1,$2,$3}' | mysql --mysqloptions
```